# Выделить текст в инпуте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть инпут куда вводиться штрих код с помощью специального аппарата. Он работает по принципу клавиатуры, написал текст и в конце нажимает Enter. Так вот когда аппарат нажимает на Enter значение должно выделяться вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это сделать через ивент?

Comment: [Статья](https://htmlweb.ru/java/example/select_input.php)

Comment: Не всё так просто. Ниже скрины прикрепил.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдаёт ошибку, как исправить? В чём проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не правильно ввёл класс, решил, спасибо!